# Make [recycler-adapter] a synonym of [android-recyclerview]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [recycler-adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recycler-adapter) tag has the following as its tag wiki:

> A RecyclerAdapter binds model data with recycling views.

There is [no such thing as RecyclerAdapter](https://www.google.com/search?q=recycleradapter&nirf=recyclerview), and on the off chance that there is, every single one of these questions is about the Android `RecyclerView` component anyway.  I'm pretty sure this is just another creative misspelling to add to the list with RecycleView, etc.

Every `RecyclerView` has a `RecyclerView.Adapter` to generate the content it displays, and it's central to the usage of a `RecyclerView`.  I can't imagine someone having expertise *specific* to RecyclerView Adapters: it's the primary way you interact with the component.

This tag only serves to cause some questions that should be tagged with [android-recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-recyclerview) to not have that tag, and thus, it should be a synonym.